# Frame issue with UINavigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am seeing this really weird issue with pushing/popping a UIViewController with custom buttons in the view. I confirmed it does not happen with other views I have like UIViewTableController, etc.. I have a function that calculates the navbar + status bar height, and then I offset my icons so their origin starts at CGMakeRect(0.0f, navbarheight+statusbarheight, ....) This looks great when I start the main screen on the phone (this view is initialized as the root view):

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28315319/photo%20%282%29.PNG

Then, when I push a new view onto the navigation controller, I see this gap appear out of nowhere. This does NOT occur on the simulator, but does occur on the phone. Again, that top button is being placed as CGMakeRect(0.0f, navbarheight+statusbarheight, ....)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28315319/photo%20%283%29.PNG

Finally, when I pop that view, my original root view contains this gap.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28315319/photo%20%281%29.PNG

No clue what is causing this to happen on the real phone (iphone 4s + iphone 5) and not the simulators. If you need more info, let me know.

UPDATE:

As far as I can tell - this is a bug in the XCode simulator not taking into account the navigationbar height. I am no longer using the simulator and just distributing it to my phone.

Comment: When you push a UIViewController onto a NavController, isnt frame origin 0.0f,0.0f still the upper right corner of the screen or is it (0.0f, navbarheight+statusbarheight) ?

Comment: It appears that the gap on the 3rd snapshot is equal to your navbar + statusbar height

Comment: Actually, i noticed the view.center  changes from the first load (160.00, 284.0) to the pop (160.00,316.0)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you still may not have `self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden` set to YES. Doing so should take the navigation bar offset into account automatically.